# Delete subscription with a form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have subscribers unsubscribe via a delete form where they enter their email and then submit and then delete the subscription. Not sure why this isn't working. I've tried a number of things via my controller. Would love some suggestions or alternatives.

Currently getting this error

```
Couldn't find Subscription without an ID
```

Subscriptions controller

```
def destroy
    @subscriptions = Subscription.all
    @subscription = @subscriptions.find(params[:id])
    if @subscription.email == params[:email]
    @subscription.destroy
            flash[:notice] = "You have been unsubscribed"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
    end
end
```

Routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  resources :posts
  root 'static_pages#new_home'

  resources :subscriptions, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  get '/home' =>  'static_pages#home'
  get 'subscriptions' => 'subscriptions#show'
  delete 'subscriptions' => 'subscriptions#destroy'
  get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get '/author' => 'static_pages#author'
  get '/contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/book' => 'static_pages#book'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Unsubscribe partial in subscriptions view

```
<%= form_for @subscription, method: :delete do |f| %>


<div class="row">
    <h2>Unsubscribe</h2>
</div>
<div class="row newsletter">
    <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
        <div class="row email-label">
        <%= f.label :email, :class => 'label-email' %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <%= f.submit 'Unsubscribe', :class => 'btn-full-subscribe' %>
      </div>
    </form>
</center
<% end %>
```

I've tried a number of things with no luck. Help would be appreciated. Thanks. Subscriptions are not related to User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `@subscription = @subscriptions.find(params[:email])` is causing the issue.

Try `@subscription = @subscriptions.find_by_email(params[:email])` or better yet, use the id `@subscription = @subscriptions.find(params[:id])`.

`ActiveRecord::find` only uses ids: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find.

Comment: Yeah, I tried just 'find(params[:id])' earlier and it was still throwing an error for some reason. I totally forgot about the find by attribute name however. Thanks. Will try

Comment: Make your changes, then update your question if you need more help!

Comment: When I use ID it still gives me Couldn't find without ID. But I want the ID correct? I think part of the issue here is using a form. However, I can't think of any other good way to do this being as I can't delete a subscription unless somebody submits their email to figure what subscription to actually delete.

Comment: You could append it to your url `DELETE /subscribtion/destroy/:id`. Or use a hidden field in your form.

Comment: I made a few changes to my forms and routes but your suggesting basically worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
@subscription = @subscriptions.find(params[:email])
```

because find uses id to fetch the record if you want to fetch by any other field use `find_by_"attribute_name"`, Replace it with

```
@subscription = Subscription.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Or no need to write down extra code. No need to fetch all the subscriptions. To delete use

```
@subscription = Subscription.find_by_email(params[:email])
or
@subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])

if @subscription.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "You have been unsubscribed"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```